# How to break lines when using wagtail BlockQuoteBlock?

Tags: python, wagtail

I have this model:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore import blocks

class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ('code', CodeBlock()),
        ('markdown', MarkDownBlock()),
        ('media', TestMediaBlock(icon='media')),
        ('blockquote', blocks.BlockQuoteBlock())
    ])
```

When I'm saving page with some text using `blockquote` I use some line breakes and even `<br>` tags:

[image]

But on the page there are no line breaks after it:

[image]

So how to make this work and save line breaks? I'm using wagtail `1.13.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was done because of security reasons. But It is possible to solve the problem - redefine `BlockQuoteBlock`  for example like this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import format_html

from wagtail.wagtailcore import blocks


class BlockQuoteBlock(blocks.TextBlock):

    def render_basic(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return format_html(
                '<blockquote>{0}</blockquote>', mark_safe(value))
        else:
            return ''

    class Meta:
        icon = "openquote"
```

I've added `mark_safe()` function to the [original implementation](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/blocks/field_block.py#L140). And then use this block in the model, if you do so, then `<br>` tags begin to work

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way would be to use Django's filter `linebreaksbr` in your template.  This converts all `"\n"` characters into `<br>` tags, so you don't have to directly inject any html when writing content.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linenumbers