# Include elements of the display code and quotes in draftail for wagtail

Tags: python, wagtail, draftjs

I'm just getting to know the Wagtail. How to configure all built-in `draftail` formats for my Wagtail.
I need to add `code` and  qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you will use `StreamField` for this purposes, I've done it in this way (wagtail 1.13.1):

**blocks.py**

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import format_html

from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import get_formatter_by_name
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name

from wagtail.wagtailcore import blocks


class CodeBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """
    Code Highlighting Block
    """
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        ('python', 'Python'),
        ('bash', 'Bash/Shell'),
        ('html', 'HTML'),
        ('css', 'CSS'),
        ('scss', 'SCSS'),
        ('json', 'JSON'),
        ('js', 'javaScript'),
        ('mysql', 'mysql'),
        ('jinja', 'jinja'),
        ('go', 'go')
    )

    STYLE_CHOICES = (
        ('default', 'default'),
        ('monokai', 'monokai'),
    )

    language = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
    style = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='default')
    code = blocks.TextBlock()

    class Meta:
        icon = 'code'

    def render(self, value, context=None):
        src = value['code'].strip('\n')
        lang = value['language']
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(lang)
        css_classes = ['code', value['style']]

        formatter = get_formatter_by_name(
            'html',
            linenos='inline',
            cssclass=' '.join(css_classes),
            noclasses=False,
        )
        return mark_safe(highlight(src, lexer, formatter))


class BlockQuoteBlock(blocks.TextBlock):

    def render_basic(self, value, context=None):
        if value:
            return format_html(
                '<blockquote>{0}</blockquote>', mark_safe(value))
        else:
            return ''

    class Meta:
        icon = "openquote"
```

**models.py**

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import StreamField
from .blocks import CodeBlock, BlockQuoteBlock
...

class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('code', CodeBlock()),
        ('blockquote', BlockQuoteBlock())
    ])
```

I've used custom `BlockQuoteBlock` because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179072/how-to-break-lines-when-using-wagtail-blockquoteblock). Also check the docs on `StreamField`: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#